# Listen to To/CC fields of Microsoft Outlook for Key up/down events

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, outlook-addin

We're trying to create an Outlook add-in that displays a custom suggestion (autocomplete) drop-down list as a person types in the To/CC field of a new Email window in Outlook. We have met a roadblock because we cannot find out how to listen to the keystroke events on these fields in Outlook. We tried using the `MailItem.PropertyChange` and `MailItem.BeforeCheckNames` but neither of them corresponds to a keystroke event or even a periodic callback.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a long shot - quite complicated but it sounds like you've already given up on the trivial solutions:

Maybe you can find the handles to the To/CC windows, and attach to their text changed?

If you run Spy++ you can see these fields are quite unique and easy to find. Then you need to run according to their re-paint or whatever.

Best of luck!
Nili